# What are the evidences, accounts and notes that prove ancient Indian empires and Chinese empires were friendly states before 300 BC

Tags: political-history, writing

What are the evidences, accounts and notes that prove ancient empires of India and China were friendly states before 300 BC?

I am personally searching for descriptions/writings of well known travelers which discuss this topic.

From [government verified source of ministry](https://www.eoibeijing.gov.in/eoibejing_pages/MjY,)

> India-China cultural exchanges date back to many centuries and there is some evidence that conceptual and linguistic exchanges existed in 1500-1000 B.C.

Comment: Where did this assertion come from? Are we trying to prove something you just made up or is there actual context and sources that you've looked at?

Comment: @BrianZ actually I require account of travellers +assertion is correct

Comment: Chinese pottery also travelled the same route,
as did textiles and spices from India and Southeast Asia. In return,
precious metals – gold and silver – flowed from Europe to Asia.As early as 3000 BCE an active coastal trade linked the Indus valley
civilisations with present-day West Asia. NCERT
https://ncert.nic.in › ncerts › jess304
NCERT – The Making of Global World

Comment: @BrianZ  government verified source https://mea.gov.in/Portal/ForeignRelation/China_October_2017.pdf page 4 India-China cultural exchanges date back to many centuries and there is some 
evidence that conceptual and linguistic exchanges existed in 1500-1000 B.C.

Comment: The countries we now call India and China did not exist back then, both had various states existing on their respective territories (e.g. in China it was the period of warring states). In what sense these states were supposed to be "friendly"? Do you mean they did not fight each?

Comment: @Hope Please edit the question to explain the references instead of burying this critical information in comments.

Comment: Consider US and PRC now: there is no war between the two countries, there is a huge trade between them. But are these friendly countries?

Comment: There's no war, soldiers go out to beat each other with clubs for the fun of it https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Indian_border_dispute

Comment: @SPavel *ancient

Comment: Commercial exchanges do not mean friendly state

Comment: Trade over very long distances is older than history.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The Chinese diplomat and explorer Zhang Qian [reported the existence of India](https://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Zhang_Qian#Shendu_.28India.29) in the 2nd century. He mentioned the existence of Shendu. The name comes from the Sanskrit word "Sindhu," used for the province of Sindh (now a province of Pakistan) by its local people. Sindh was one of the most advanced regions of India at the time. Notice - there were no direct contacts, only a mention of existence.
2. The  Yuezhi, an Indo-European people also known as the Kushans, are mentioned in the "Records of the Three Kingdoms" in connection with diplomatic interactions with China. The Yuezhi established a powerful kingdom in Central Asia, and they played a significant role in the Silk Road trade network. While not explicitly mentioned as "India," the Yuezhi had interactions with Indian territories, and their presence is indicative of some connections between China and the Indian subcontinent.

So, according to the known Chinese documents, there were no direct diplomatic connections between Indian and Chinese states, let alone friendly treaties. They merely sometimes heard that there was something somewhere in that direction.

Comment: What about lot of accounts by buddhist travellers from China to india. There are many accounts in my course book.

Comment: @Hope The question is not about personal contacts. It is about the friendly treaties of states. Of course, there were many religious and commercial contacts. The last ones included the slave trade in these times. Surely, there were pretty Indian girls in the Chinese harems and vice versa. These contacts were very close and more than friendly. But still, they were not even diplomatic contacts, let alone friendly treaties.

Answer (score 2):

A [Google search for that quote](https://www.google.com/search?q=ndia-China+cultural+exchanges+date+back+to+many+centuries+and+there+is+some+evidence+that+conceptual+and+linguistic+exchanges+existed+in+1500-1000+B.C.) provides a surprising number of examples with suspiciously similar phrasing.  Within those, the one that looks best is [Ijhssi.org](https://www.ijhssi.org/papers/vol9(7)/Ser-1/D0907012126.pdf), but even that source provides no citations.

[Some linguistic evidence for early cultural exchange between China and India](https://www.sino-platonic.org/complete/spp066_india_china.pdf) in Sino Platonic papers seems to possibly be original research.